# Asp.Net:  Save File at Path Location

Tags: c#, asp.net

I uploaded pdf files on client side.

I passed path location to `.ashx file`, from this i have path location in string variable. I need to save this file in that path location.

please help.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It doesnt really make much sense at the moment.

Comment: Downvoting, since someone helped you and you didn't respond to them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rootPath` is a variable containing the root path, and `fileName` is the name of the file you wish to save:

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(rootPath, fileName);
```

I don't know what form the file exists in. If you include that, I can give better instructions on what to do with `filePath` from there.

```
using (var outputStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    // write to outputStream; depends on what form your PDF file is in at this point.
}
```